# How do I cite references in a document which contains multiple .tex files but uses a single bibliography section?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm currently writing a large document in overleaf which contains multiple .tex files which are all compiled into a single pdf using \include in the main.tex. I have made a references.bib file and am trying to cite references that are in there.

The problem I'm having right now is that I can only seem to cite in one .tex file (introduction) and if I try using \cite in another section file it just doesn't appear in my references. I have already checked the main file in the menu and it is correct (main.tex).

The only code in my main.tex about my bibliography is:

```
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{References}
```

My References.bib file contains the correctly formatted bibtex references.

I have used \usepackage{natbib} but I don't think this does anything.
I haven't written anything else in my other .tex files about the bibliography besides using \cite.

I hope you can help, have looked elsewhere online but couldn't find the same problem.

Comment: How do you compile the document? On your local system, or online on Overleaf? If you compile locally, did you run Bibtex again after adding references? If so, on which file? Please add a complete overview to your question with details on all the compile steps and editor settings. Another possibility is that there is an error in either the LaTeX code or in the references file that prevents compilation from succeeding and updating the citation list, try to locate the LaTeX and Bibtex log files to see if they report any error messages.

Comment: The problem is fixed, oversaw an easy error because I was losing my sanity looking at this problem. I had a whitespace in my filename... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, good that it is fixed, I have voted to close the question as caused by a typo.